# SQL Adding a Column Based on condition and counter

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a very large table which contains

[image: Table]

I need to flag every row based on two rules;

1. If the condition is 1 then the flag should be negative
2. All the flags are positive except the one coming immediately after fifth one which should be negative, so for every 5 positive ones, the next should be negative.
3. The flag resets for each ID ( name ), so even if the last flag of John is Positive, Amy starts fresh with 5 positive flags.

I am trying to this on hive, so that I can not update the existing tables.

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL <> Hive. Tag spam doesn't help us help you; it makes it harder to. Tagging multiple conflicting tags means that we have no idea what technology you are really asking about, making your question unclear and difficult to answer. Tagging completely irrelevant technologies just wastes the time of the subject experts you attract that know nothing about the technology you are *actually* asking about. Either way, tag spam can easily end up attracting downvotes and also close votes if they make the question unclear. Just tag the technologies you are actually asking about.

Comment: This will need database dependant functions please tag the database and version that you are using.

Comment: Thank you very much both, added the tag, it is Postgresql running on Hive

Comment: Please give table definition and sample data as text - thanks. How are the records of a user ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view of the added condition that the count of 5 must restart after each expected which is negatif because of the condition being 1 I have found a new solution.
We create a temporary table, with make expected of the lowest ID of a user 1, and all the rows where condition = 1. We then run our query checking the last 4 lines using the function LAG().
Note that 1 means negatif! You could try to modify the query to adjust the value shown.

> ```
> create table outcomes(
> id serial ,
> username varchar(10),
> dollars int,
> condition int,
> expected varchar(10));
> ```

> ```
> insert into outcomes
> (username,condition) values
> ('John',1),('John',0),('John',0),('John',0),
>  ('John',0),('John',0),('John',0),('John',0),
>  ('John',0),('John',0),('John',1),('John',0),
> ('Amy',0),('Amy',0),('Amy',0),('Amy',0),
>  ('Amy',0),('Amy',0),('Amy',0),('Amy',0),
>  ('Amy',1),('Amy',0),('Amy',0);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TEMP TABLE expected AS
> SELECT 
>   id,
>   username,
>   dollars,
>   condition,
>   case when condition = 1 then 1
>        else 0 end expected
> FROM outcomes;
> ```

> ```
> update expected set expected = 1 
> where id in
> (select min(id) from expected group by username);
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   id, 
>   username,
>   condition,
>   case when expected = 1 then 1
>   when
>   lag(expected,5) over (order by username, id) = 1 and 
>   coalesce(lag(expected,1) over (order by username, id),0) +
>   coalesce(lag(expected,2) over (order by username, id),0) +
>   coalesce(lag(expected,3) over (order by username, id),0) +
>   coalesce(lag(expected,4) over (order by username, id),0) = 0 then 1
>   else 0 end expected
> from
> expected
> ```
>
> ```
> id | username | condition | expected
> -: | :------- | --------: | -------:
> 13 | Amy      |         0 |        1
> 14 | Amy      |         0 |        0
> 15 | Amy      |         0 |        0
> 16 | Amy      |         0 |        0
> 17 | Amy      |         0 |        0
> 18 | Amy      |         0 |        1
> 19 | Amy      |         0 |        0
> 20 | Amy      |         0 |        0
> 21 | Amy      |         1 |        1
> 22 | Amy      |         0 |        0
> 23 | Amy      |         0 |        0
>  1 | John     |         1 |        1
>  2 | John     |         0 |        0
>  3 | John     |         0 |        0
>  4 | John     |         0 |        0
>  5 | John     |         0 |        0
>  6 | John     |         0 |        1
>  7 | John     |         0 |        0
>  8 | John     |         0 |        0
>  9 | John     |         0 |        0
> 10 | John     |         0 |        0
> 11 | John     |         1 |        1
> 12 | John     |         0 |        0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7bb845cfbec9122af4fa9fc402722069)*

Answer (score 1):

Here we use RANK() in a CTE to get count the rows per user. We then use CASE and integer division by 5 to find the multiplies of 5 and apply the 2 tests.

> ```
> create table outcomes(
> id serial ,
> username varchar(10),
> dollars int,
> condition int,
> expected varchar(10));
> ```

> ```
> insert into outcomes
> (username,condition) values
> ('John',1),('John',0),('John',0),('John',0),
>  ('John',0),('John',0),('John',0),('John',0),
>  ('John',0),('John',0),('John',1),('John',0),
> ('Amy',0),('Amy',0),('Amy',0),('Amy',0),
>  ('Amy',0),('Amy',0),('Amy',0),('Amy',0),
>  ('Amy',1),('Amy',0),('Amy',0);
> ```

> ```
> with cte as 
> (select *,
> rank() over (partition
> by username order by id) rn
> from Outcomes)
> select 
>   id,
>   username, 
>   condition,
>   rn,
>   case
>    when condition = 1 then '- negative'
>    when 5*(rn/5)=rn then '- negative'
>    else 'positive' end expectedOutcome
>  from cte;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | username | condition | rn | expectedoutcome
> -: | :------- | --------: | -: | :--------------
> 13 | Amy      |         0 |  1 | positive       
> 14 | Amy      |         0 |  2 | positive       
> 15 | Amy      |         0 |  3 | positive       
> 16 | Amy      |         0 |  4 | positive       
> 17 | Amy      |         0 |  5 | - negative     
> 18 | Amy      |         0 |  6 | positive       
> 19 | Amy      |         0 |  7 | positive       
> 20 | Amy      |         0 |  8 | positive       
> 21 | Amy      |         1 |  9 | - negative     
> 22 | Amy      |         0 | 10 | - negative     
> 23 | Amy      |         0 | 11 | positive       
>  1 | John     |         1 |  1 | - negative     
>  2 | John     |         0 |  2 | positive       
>  3 | John     |         0 |  3 | positive       
>  4 | John     |         0 |  4 | positive       
>  5 | John     |         0 |  5 | - negative     
>  6 | John     |         0 |  6 | positive       
>  7 | John     |         0 |  7 | positive       
>  8 | John     |         0 |  8 | positive       
>  9 | John     |         0 |  9 | positive       
> 10 | John     |         0 | 10 | - negative     
> 11 | John     |         1 | 11 | - negative     
> 12 | John     |         0 | 12 | positive
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fa65d2fd894a4fc0f4343bb44f021a08)*

Comment: Thank you very much, just what I needed, cheers!

Comment: on second look, the counter needs to reset after each negative, so  22 | Amy      |         0 | 10 | - negative needs to be positive as well, because even though it is multiple of 5, the multiple of 5 needs to reset after each negative be it a condition or every fifth.

Comment: I have no idea how that works, if you can help I will really appreciate it